# Symmetric Key Creation Question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, encryption

I am going through the [CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql) page.

In there it says as a Caution

> **When a symmetric key is encrypted with a password instead of the
>   public key of the database master key,** the TRIPLE DES encryption
>   algorithm is used. Because of this, keys that are created with a
>   strong encryption algorithm, such as AES, are themselves secured by a
>   weaker algorithm.

I do not understand the first part in bold and have a couple of questions.

1. From my testing I do not see an option to encrypt a symmetric key
   with Database Master key.
2. Isn't the Database master key a Symmetric key.  What do they mean by
       public key of th database master key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct and the docs need updating.  Should probably read:

> When a symmetric key is encrypted with a password instead of a
>   certificate (or another key), the TRIPLE DES encryption algorithm is
>   used to encrypt the password. Because of this, keys that are created
>   with a strong encryption algorithm, such as AES, are themselves
>   secured by a weaker algorithm.

learn.microsoft.com is all on GitHub, so you can propose doc changes.

I've submitted a pull request to update the language.  You can follow it here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/310